# How to use IEnumerable<T> in a class constructor parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make some code in my MVC controller (export to Excel) more generic, as I've reached the point where I'm typing out almost identical code in multiple controllers. To make the export to Excel function so that exists in only one place -- rather than in many places -- I had the idea of using a generic IEnumerable so I could feed *any* IEnumerable into the class. (See code block below.)

I know that I can use byte[] as a parameter (and I might still use that as an other constructor choice), but it would be nice if I could use an IEnumerable in this instance.

However, Intellisense immediately tells me that "the type or namespace T could not be found".

Is is possible to use `IEnumerable<T>` for this purpose?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.CentralFunctions
{
    public class ExportToExcel
    {
        ExportToExcel(IEnumerable<T> inputCollection)
        {
            // TODO: place my "export to excel" commands here.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define what `T` represents to the compiler somewhere. Since you are dealing with a class constructor, you need to make the class generic in order to define `T`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.CentralFunctions
{
    public class ExportToExcel<T>
    {
        ExportToExcel(IEnumerable<T> inputCollection)
        {
            // TODO: place my "export to excel" commands here.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `T` type is «unknown», i.e. not specified.

It seems you want to make the `ExportToExcel` class [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx), and the `T` seems to be a type parameter:

```
public class ExportToExcel<T>
{
    ExportToExcel(IEnumerable<T> inputCollection)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your T type at class level, If you want you can also add a constraint to T

```
public class ExportToExcel<T>
{
    ExportToExcel(IEnumerable<T> inputCollection)
    {
        // TODO: place my "export to excel" commands here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted @NightOwl888 as the best answer. Thank you to @Sergei and @Luke for also answering.

Their answers helped me to write the class constructor correctly and now I can greatly simplify my code. I am sharing this because it explains the full context of the question and demonstrates how I can place it into my MVC system. This is the "hello world" version and can serve to help others like me who are figuring out how to get started.

Now I can simplify the controller action to this:

**View:**

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel","ExportToExcel")</p>
```

**Controller Action:**

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
{
    IEnumerable<TroveLog> data = db.TroveLogs.AsEnumerable();
    var export = new ExportToExcel<TroveLog>(data);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And this is where I can place the single block of code that can export *any* IEnumerable to Excel.  When I use Debug mode (F5), I can see the `Debug.WriteLine` results and verify that I am seeing the correct information.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.CentralFunctions
{
    public class ExportToExcel<T>
    {
        private IEnumerable<T> data;

        public ExportToExcel(IEnumerable<T> inputCollection)
        {
            this.data = inputCollection;               

            // Run in Debug Mode (F5) and see results when clicking ActionLink.
            Debug.WriteLine("Object: {0}", data.GetType());
            Debug.WriteLine("RowCount: {0}", data.Count());

            // TODO: place my "export to excel" commands here.
        }    
    }
}
```